# android: delete history after homepage load

Tags: android, browser-history

hey, an android noob needs help here.

i'm trying to get my webview browser to **delete** the browser **history** after the **homepage** has been loaded (so the next user that comes around this public app doesn't see the previous session)

i've made a webview client and put a

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String Url ) {
     Browser.clearHistory();
```

but don't know how to change the *String Url* to the url of the apps  homepage.

*I also tried adding a second function to my homebutton onclicklistener, but no luck as well, if someone wants to help i can paste that bit of code as well.*

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here how I did;

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    junc.pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if(url.indexOf("a_string_unique_to_your_homepage")!=-1) {
        view.clearHistory();
    }
}
```

Here, you can define a unique string for your url. For example if your homepage url is

```
www.example.com
```

you can call it with

```
www.example.com?12345abc
```

and search for this unique number 12345abc.
It works, I have tested several times.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Matt you can´t delete your Browser history programatically in Android.

you will achieve that manually
Browser ..> Settings > Clear History > OK

Comment: He's using a webview, not the native browser. So there's no menu as mentioned available.

Comment: had a similar response about the android browser (not the webview browser I built) yesterday, but it disappeared over night :)
got it fixed by wiping the history and the cookies (to logout google account in webview) at onPause and still had one history item left, so my GF figured cleaning the history with `if CanGoBack` at onResume would fix it. It did, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
Browser.clearSearches(getContentResolver());
```